# Different ways of proving that $|\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}(1-\cos(1/k))|\leq 2 $

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

I've found two ways of proving that 
\begin{align} \left|\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\left[1-\cos\left(\dfrac{1}{k}\right)\right]\right|&\leq 2   \end{align}
Are there any other ways out there, for proving this?

**METHOD 1**

Let $k\in \Bbb{N}$, then

\begin{align} f:[ 0&,1]\longrightarrow \Bbb{R}\\&x \mapsto 
\cos\left(\dfrac{x}{k}\right)   \end{align}
is continuous. Then, by Mean Value Theorem, there exists $c\in [ 0,x]$ such that 
\begin{align} \cos\left(\dfrac{x}{k}\right)-\cos\left(0\right) =-\dfrac{1}{k}\sin\left(\dfrac{c}{k}\right)\,(x-0), \end{align}
which implies \begin{align} \left|\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\left[1-\cos\left(\dfrac{1}{k}\right)\right]\right| &=\left|\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\dfrac{x}{k}\sin\left(\dfrac{c}{k}\right)\right| \leq \sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\dfrac{\left|x\right|}{k}\left|\sin\left(\dfrac{c}{k}\right)\right|\leq \sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\dfrac{\left|x\right|}{k}\dfrac{\left|c\right|}{k}\\&\leq \sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\left(\dfrac{\left|x\right|}{k}\right)^2\leq \sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\dfrac{1}{k^2}=1+ \sum^{\infty}_{k=2}\dfrac{1}{k^2}\\&\leq 1+ \sum^{\infty}_{k=2}\dfrac{1}{k(k-1)}\\&= 1+ \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum^{n}_{k=2}\left(\dfrac{1}{k-1}-\dfrac{1}{k}\right)\\&=1+ \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(1-\dfrac{1}{n}\right)\\&=2, \end{align}

**METHOD 2**

Let $x\in [0,1]$ be fixed, then
\begin{align} \sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\left[1-\cos\left(\dfrac{1}{k}\right)\right]&=\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\dfrac{1}{k}\left[-k\cos\left(\dfrac{x}{k}\right)\right]^{1}_{0}=\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\dfrac{1}{k}\int^{1}_{0}\sin\left(\dfrac{x}{k}\right)dx \\&=\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\int^{1}_{0}\dfrac{1}{k}\sin\left(\dfrac{x}{k}\right)dx  \end{align}
The series $\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\dfrac{1}{k}\sin\left(\dfrac{x}{k}\right)$ converges uniformly on $[0,1]$, by Weierstrass-M test, since
\begin{align} \left|\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\dfrac{1}{k}\sin\left(\dfrac{x}{k}\right) \right|\leq \sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\dfrac{1}{k}\left|\sin\left(\dfrac{x}{k}\right) \right|\leq \sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\dfrac{1}{k^2}. \end{align}
Hence, 
\begin{align} \sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\left[1-\cos\left(\dfrac{1}{k}\right)\right]&=\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\int^{1}_{0}\dfrac{1}{k}\sin\left(\dfrac{x}{k}\right)dx=\int^{1}_{0}\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\dfrac{1}{k}\sin\left(\dfrac{x}{k}\right)dx,  \end{align}
and 
\begin{align} \left|\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\left[1-\cos\left(\dfrac{1}{k}\right)\right]\right|&=\left|\int^{1}_{0}\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\dfrac{1}{k}\sin\left(\dfrac{x}{k}\right)dx\right|\leq\int^{1}_{0}\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\dfrac{1}{k}\left|\sin\left(\dfrac{x}{k}\right)\right|dx \\&\leq\int^{1}_{0}\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\dfrac{1}{k^2}dx \\&\leq 2 \end{align}

Comment: Nice work! (+1) Do you know if the series $$\sum_{n\geq1}1-\cos(1/k)$$ Has a closed form?

Comment: Hmm... I don't know but do you have an idea its closed form?

Comment: I do not. It looks a lot like a Fourier series though. Special functions may help...

Comment: @clathratus: Kindly see Robert Israel's answer for a closed form.

Comment: Hi @Mike ! I would like to learn how to evaluate to solve some problems like the one you posted, but I've never seen such problems in my Analysis books. Could you please share how you learned to solve them and if there is any resource with many problems like this, either teaching you how to do them or just many practice problems?

Comment: @Ovi: Yes, I do have some books too. If you don't mind, I'd send some to you in the morning. Will have some rest now. Will chat you up in the morning or better still, my email is: momojola@aust.edu.ng

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using the Maclaurin series for $\cos$,
your sum is $$S = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{j+1}}{(2j)!\; k^{2j}}$$
This converges absolutely, and 
$$ |S| \le \sum_{j=1}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2j)!\; k^{2j}} = \sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{\zeta(2j)}{(2j)!} \le \sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{\zeta(2)}{(2j)!} =\frac{(\cosh(1)-1) \pi^2}{6} < 2$$
(in fact $< 0.9$).

Comment: I love this method!

Answer (score 8):

Note that 
$$1 - \cos(x) = \cos(0) - \cos(x) = 2 \sin^2\left( \frac{x}2 \right) $$
by the [sum to product identities](http://www.sosmath.com/trig/prodform/prodform.html) for all $x$. Therefore,

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left(1- \cos\left( \frac{1}k \right) \right) = 2 \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \sin^2\left( \frac{1}{2k} \right). $$
Now using the inequality $\sin(x) \le x$ for all positive $x$, we get
$$ 2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \sin^2\left( \frac{1}{2k} \right) \le \frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^2} \approx 0.822.$$

Comment: You should say $|\sin x| \le |x|$ for all $x.$ (Minor quibble.)

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Thanks I made it slightly better

Answer (score 5):

Another method which gives a better bound than  $2$ is the following: the inequality $1-\cos\, x \leq \frac {x^{2}} 2$ holds for all real $x$ and $\sum \frac 1 {k^{2}} =\frac {\pi^{2}} 6$. Use the fact that $\frac {\pi^{2}} {12}<2$. [ $1-\cos\, x - \frac {x^{2}} 2$ vanishes at $0$ and its derivative is $\sin\, x -x <0$. This gives the inequality above]. Note that LHS $<1$ in fact!

Comment: I did not downvote, but perhaps the down vote is due to the similarity to the second method above? Although this is perhaps cleaner and more clear, too.

Comment: @Clayton right... Thanks. It's not my day :(

Comment: I like this approach!

Answer (score 4):

Using the Taylor series of the $\cos$ function, your sum is equal to the much faster converging $\sum_{n\ge 1} (-1)^{n+1}\frac{\zeta(2n)}{(2n)!}$. Summing the first two terms, $\pi^2/12-\pi^4/2160$, gives a value of $\approx 0.7773$ with an error of $\epsilon_1\approx1.388\times 10^{-3}$. By contrast, summing two terms of your original sum will give you $\approx 0.5821$, this time with a larger error of $\epsilon_2 \approx .1942$.

To answer your question, we can use a theorem about alternating series, which states that for $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^{k+1} a_k$ and $S=\lim_{n\to\infty}S_n$, we have that
$$|S-S_n|< a_{n+1}$$
Using the same two terms as above, we can see that $S<\pi^6/680400 - \pi^4/2160 + \pi^2/12\approx 0.7788$. Thus,

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty 1-\cos(1/k) < 0.78 <2$$

Comment: (+1) for that. Looks good!